# Disabling mouse wheel zoom using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, zoom, mouse-wheel

The mouse wheel behaviour in the 4.1 version of the ArcGIS JS API is causing problems with maps on scrollable pages, see [Scrolling down a page with a map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193902) from here and [a question on esri.com](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/177238#comment-639376). I thought I'd disable zoom by mouse wheel altogether until this is fixed, but I can't find how.

For 3.18 this should be possible using the disableScrollWheelZoom() method, but this isn't supported in 4.1. Does anyone know the 4.1 equivalent?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this? As far as I can tell this has not been address and isn't fixed yet.

Comment: Didn't get an answer, did find a workaround however. See the answer here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/177970#comment-612463

Comment: This workaround worked for me, you should add it as a self-answer!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've been able to find, this is not possible in ArcGIS. I've tried every single solution that I could find and thought about trying to do some kind of overlay.

Instead I opted to use openlayers 3 and implemented the solution below. Works perfectly. Outlined here: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Advanced-Features-of-an-OpenLayers-3-Map

```
  map.getInteractions().forEach(function(interaction) {
    if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom) {
      interaction.setActive(false);
    }
  }, this);
```